# Error code ERR_DLOPEN_FAILED -when I try to install vite

Tags: visual-studio-code, vite

I'm new to coding. I'm following a tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QRrPE9aj3wI&t=621s&ab_channel=JavaScriptMastery.
I keep getting this error. I have tried to uninstall vite and reinstall it. I would love any answer to this problem. I have tried to look at other post on different sites and they don't apply to me or don't work.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to chatGPT to answer my error. I had to download Visual C++ Redistributable. The link is: https://aka.ms/vs/17/release/vc_redist.x64.exe.